# Error while running uiautomatorviewer in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

When I run the uiautomatorviewer, I get the following error:
**/android-sdk-linux/tools$**

```
uiautomatorviewerException in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale.getExtensionKeys()Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale$Builder.setLocale(ULocale.java:4011)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.addULocale(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:204)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.getLocales(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:140)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.getAvailableLocales(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:53)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.text.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderICU.getAvailableLocales(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderICU.java:28)
    at sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getProviderLocales(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:235)
    at sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObjectImpl(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:370)
    at sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObject(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:303)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:150)
    at java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2251)
    at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1877)
    at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1898)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2792)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.checkAdbVersion(AndroidDebugBridge.java:583)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.<init>(AndroidDebugBridge.java:559)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge(AndroidDebugBridge.java:319)
    at com.android.uiautomator.DebugBridge.init(DebugBridge.java:68)
    at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:71)
```

could anybody help me out?

thanks for your time.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano : This is the java version I am using,
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4 (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Mine is java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano installed the same version which you are using - java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode).  I still get the same error, when i run $uiautomatorviewer  :(

Answer (score 1):

Since my tools/ directory is not added in the PATH. I used  $./uiautomatorviewer command to run my uiautomatorviewer and it worked. Thanks @DiegoTorresMilano for the suggestion